# An invalid merchant configuration in Paypal with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I am making the paypal application with rails. 
I have create all the necessary a/c in http://develpers.paypal.com and also have insert all that information in my rails app.
My problem is when i am trying to authorize my seller a/c, it gives me error like 
"Failure: This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration."

My code is:

```
# all inforation is of seller API id, password, signature
gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.new(
        :login => "seller_1302505219_biz_api1.gmail.com",
        :password => "...",
        :signature => "..." 
      )

options = {
  :ip => request.remote_ip,
  :billing_address => {
    :name     => "Name",
    :address1 => '1 Main St',
    :address2 => '',
    :city     => 'San Jose',
    :state    => 'CA',
    :country  => 'US',
    :zip      => '95131',
    # :phone    => '408-983-5678'
    :phone    => '408-678-0945'
  }
}
res = gateway.authorize(amount, credit_card, options)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.
I have google it but got the information about the "Billing agreement".
But that functionality is provided in Website Payment Pro. 
so I have just create an test account using WPP and use that WPP account credential for transaction.
It works fine.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a seller account set up with Website Payments Pro.

1. Create your selling test account using the **Preconfigured** option.
2. Under **Account Type**, select **Website Payments Pro**.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have already found it and also answered it.

Comment: I had the same problem you did, and found this to be the simplest solution.  I posted it for others who have the same problem and find this post.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, your account may or may not be enabled for Pro (DoDirectPayment) even after signing up for it in Sandbox. There's a thread on the x.com forums where you can ask one of the support guys to enable it for you.

Comment: yeah. Thanks buddy. And one more that you can email to "webmaster@paypal.com"