# Active Merchant With Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activemerchant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An invalid merchant configuration in Paypal with rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618088/an-invalid-merchant-configuration-in-paypal-with-rails)

I am playing with the Active Merchant gem. I used [Rails cast(144)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/144-active-merchant-basics?view=similar) and I created a ruby file (`credit_card.rb`):

```
require "rubygems"
require "active_merchant"

ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test

gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.new(
  :login => "seller_1316503855_biz_api1.agileblaze111.com",
  :password => "********",
  :signature => "A5llddES-nIiDc8WBuZMOtm6yM2oANQrerVY20ty0ZxeN-izmKjwDtR0"
)

credit_card = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
  :type               => "visa",
  :number             => "4234609806354393",
  :verification_value => "123",
  :month              =>  '9',
  :year               =>  '2016',
  :first_name         => "shamith",
  :last_name          => "c"
)

billing_address = { 
    :name     => "John Smith",
    :address1 => '123 First St.',
    :address2 => '33333',
    :city     => 'Los Angeles',
    :state    => 'CA',
    :country  => 'US',
    :zip      => '90068',
    :phone    => '310-555-1234'
}

 billing_address1 = {
    :name => 'Test User',
    :company => '',
    :address1 => '123 S Main St',
    :address2 => '',
    :city => 'Akron',
    :state => 'OH',
    :country => 'US',
    :zip => '44333',
    :phone => '(310)555-5555'
  } 


if credit_card.valid?
  puts "Credit Card is valid"
  response=gateway.purchase(1000,credit_card,:ip=>"127.0.0.1",:billing_address=>billing_address1)
  if response.success?
     puts "Purchased"
  else
     puts "Error:#{response.message}"
  end
else
  puts "Error: credit card is not valid. #{credit_card.errors.full_messages.join('. ')}"end
```

I execute `$ ruby credit_card.rb` and get the following error:

```
Error: This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.
```

Answer (score 1):

Something is incorrect with your `ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway` line. I recently went through this as well, and hit that problem.

I posted [this link](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPNVPAPIBasics#id084E30I30RO) to the Paypal documentation in the comments to that episode. There they describe the current process to get the API credentials you need, as the rails cast is about two years old and slightly out of date.

I had multiple problems with my sandbox account not being the correct type and not having the correct credentials.

One helpful thing I eventually found was, on the developers site, where you can create new sandbox accounts and such, there's a link on the left-hand side where you can view any API credentials that your sandbox accounts have generated. Mine were blank when I found that link, which is what lead me to creating a new sandbox account and following the Paypal documentation method to getting credentials.

Please post if this helps or if it doesn't, as I'm still learning how to use active_merchant and the Paypal sandbox and need all the practice I can get.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a seller account set up with Website Payments Pro.

1. Create your selling test account using the **Preconfigured** option.
2. Under **Account Type**, select **Website Payments Pro**.

Good luck!